# iFrame in Wordpress only shows up in Safari

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone tell me, why my iFrame only is visible when i use Safari? You can see the site here: http://www.jak.as/job-hos-jak/

Code for the iFrame.

```
<div id="c258" class="csc-default" style="color: #ffffff;">
<div class="tx-ffiframe-pi1" style="font-style: inherit;">
<iframe id="hr-manager" style="font-style: inherit;" src="https://candidate.hr-manager.net/vacancies/list.aspx?departmentId=1321&customer=ndi_dk"
width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right below

"Ledige stillinger

Tør du tage udfordringen op? – Søg direkte via stillingsopslagene nedenfor."

Comment: Your code works fine in JSFiddle as a straight copy and paste, so I would imagine there's some styling elsewhere in your site that's stopping it from being visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inline style when inspecting attached to the `<iframe>` that looks like this:

```
iframe {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This is causing the iframe to be hidden. Reversing these values in your iframe code will make it appear.

```
<div id="c258" class="csc-default" style="color: #ffffff;">
<div class="tx-ffiframe-pi1" style="font-style: inherit;">
<iframe id="hr-manager" style="visibility:visible; opacity:1; font-style: inherit;" src="https://candidate.hr-manager.net/vacancies/list.aspx?departmentId=1321&customer=ndi_dk"
width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```